# Force Vagrant to re-provision or download a new box on next vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

If I change the provision scripts or worse yet, the base OS, is there a way to force vagrant to either re-provision or re-download the base box?  I tried to change the `config.vm.box` and `config.vm.box_url`, but `vagrant up` still happily booted up to old box.

I know I could use `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision` for just re-provisioning on my own machine, but I'm talking about a way that automatically force my team to re-provision / reinitialize the box (e.g. after they do a `git pull` and then a `vagrant up` have it either re-provision or reinitialize appropriately.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vagrant box --help` gives you some options.
Specifically, you can `vagrant box remove <name> <provider>` to remove a box, and force a re-provisioning.

For example, to remove the Vagrant sample box:

```
vagrant box remove precise32 virtualbox
```

Comment: Minor note for people coming to this answer later - the second argument is set to be removed, currently deprecated as of writing this, so you would need to pass `--provider virtualbox` instead

Comment: If the box is already provisioned, removing the base box did nothing to force a reprovision.  Only a vagrant destroy, vagrant up works to download and deploy off a new base.